# Converting from SQL into Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I am trying to convert this from SQL into a Power BI measure but receive no value after running the measure. This is the SQL code:

```
sum(case when(tbl.Category = '' and (tbl.Name like 'N%' or tbl.Name like 'S%' or tbl.Name like 'T%')) then tbl.Weight/2000 else 0 end)
    as 'Total Tons'
```

This is what I tried in Power BI. Is it an issue of the wildcard (does PowerBI recognize the % as include whatever after starting with T,S, or N)?

```
TonsMeasure = 
CALCULATE(
    [Totaltons/2000],
    tbl[Category] = "", 
    tbl[Name] = "N%", 
    tbl[Name] = "T%", 
    tbl[Name] = "S%"
)
```

Comment: Is that a per row calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
Measure = sumx(t, switch( true, (left(t[name],1)="N" || left(t[name],1)="S" || left(t[name],1)="T") &&  t[cat]=" ",  divide (t[weight],2000)))
```

Comment: I am trying to get it to include any names that start with N and follow with any amount of characters, but it isn't including that, only the ""

Comment: The tsql cide you provided, according to that find tbl.Name that starts either with N or S or T and tbl.Cat=" ". Are you trying to translate the same conditions to DAX or something else ?

Comment: Yes  I am trying to translate the same conditions

Comment: `left(t[name],1)="N" || left(t[name],1)="S" || left(t[name],1)="T") &&  t[cat]=" "` checks for that condition in Dax ? Does the code above not return what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for new column per row based on other values in the row, you can try this below measure-

```
TonsMeasure = 
IF(
    min(tbl[Category]) = ""
    && (
        LEFT(min(tbl[Name]),1) = "N" ||
        LEFT(min(tbl[Name]),1) = "T" ||
        LEFT(min(tbl[Name]),1) = "S"
    ),
    min(tbl.Weight)/2000,
    0
)
```